# How to speed up GEE calculation?

Tags: google-earth-engine, optimization

Recently, when calculating high-precision remote sensing data products, the calculation speed is very slow. I want to know how can I speed up my calculation, pay for it or other methods?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Reduce the area you are analyzing or increase the scale at which you perform calculations (such as reduceRegion); otherwise sometimes the time of day influences the speed of the cloud, that's about it I think